# Plotting Functions

Tags: python, function

I need to creat using matplotlib a single figure with the functions: y=10*x-4 and y=x². The graph must look exactly as shown below:

[image]

I did this, but i can't result the same graph: [My graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHNEH.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_graph():
    x = range(0,1000)
    y1 = [(10*a)-4 for a in x]
    y2 = [a**2 for a in x]
    plt.plot(x,y1, "r-", label = "y=10.x-4")
    plt.axis([0,1000, 1, 100000])
    plt.plot(x,y2, "g-", label = "y=x²")
    plt.legend(loc = "lower right")
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.title('My first graph in Machine Learning class')
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.grid(True)
plot_graph()
```

Comment: The graph in your question (not the one you generated yourself) seems to have the labels wrong. The green line ( labelled `f(x) = x^2`) has `f(1000) = 10^4` which is incorrect as `1000^2 = 10^6`. The red line looks very much like `f(x) = x`.